# How to maintain session in different tabs of same browser?

Tags: asp.net, session

My website is used to administer customer accounts. If I access CustomerA's account through the website then open a new tab and access CustomerB's account the session holding the customer ID updates to think I'm now working on CustomerB. Then if I click back to CustomerA's tab and start editing that page I am in fact editing the database record for CustomerB. This has happened and caused all sorts of problems so I need to find a fool proof way of stopping it. I don't want to put the customer ID in the URL as this will make it open to abuse.

Comment: On page load save customer id to viewstate, and on postback check if viewstate's customer id = session's custom id, then you are good! else just discard and show error message.

Comment: If you don't want to expose the ID, take the customerID; generate a random token and add the token to the URL. Keep the link between the token and the ID in memory. Still you need to validate it because security by obscurity does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Session is not a place to hold information like this exactly because of problems you're describing. You need to pass customer ID along with the page itself (either in hidden field or in url), so when you post back the form, it exactly knows what are you trying to do. Session won't protect you nor add any extra security. You need to determine if the user has correct permissions either way, so you should focus on this aspect.